# String Table Resource in Native Executable

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winapi, exe

Using C#, can I modify the string table resource of a native windows executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no support for doing that in the .NET Framework. You'll probably have to [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) [BeginUpdateResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [UpdateResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [EndUpdateResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from your code.

You can find an example of modifying resources in unmanaged code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources). Although it involves dialog boxes instead of string tables, it might give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks!  Your links led me [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread322160.html) and [here](http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-add-resources-to-native-executable-file-with-updateresource/).  I'll give it a shot and see if I can get it working.

Comment: String tables are more involved than other resources types. Complete native code example can be found at [updating a string table with UpdateResource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14089163/1889329).