# How to replace the RCData of an executable?

Tags: c++, winapi, autohotkey

I'm trying to modify the `RCData` of a compiled AutoHotkey script:

```
   void ReplaceStringTable() {

    HANDLE hRes = BeginUpdateResource( _T( "C:\\Users\\CAIO\\Documents\\Github\\main\\scripts\\ahkDebug\\Novo(a) AutoHotkey Script.exe" ), FALSE );
    if ( hRes != NULL ) {
        std::wstring data[] = { L"MsgBox Test" };

        std::vector< WORD > buffer;
        for ( size_t index = 0;
              index < sizeof( data ) / sizeof( data[ 0 ] );
              ++index ) {

            size_t pos = buffer.size();
            buffer.resize( pos + data[ index ].size() + 1 );
            buffer[ pos++ ] = static_cast< WORD >( data[ index ].size() );
            copy( data[ index ].begin(), data[ index ].end(),
                  buffer.begin() + pos );
        }
        UpdateResource( hRes,
                        RT_RCDATA,
                        L">AUTOHOTKEY SCRIPT<", //MAKEINTRESOURCE( 1 ),
                        1033, //MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT ),
                        reinterpret_cast< void* >( &buffer[ 0 ] ),
                        buffer.size() * sizeof( WORD ) );

        EndUpdateResource( hRes, FALSE );
    }
}
```

However, this is the result after running the code:

[image: RCData]

The code does add an empty blank line (line 1), this line makes the exe not work correctly, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Quote from the [documentation of `BeginUpdateResourceW` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-beginupdateresourcew): _If this parameter is `TRUE`, existing resources are deleted and the updated file includes only resources added with the UpdateResource function._

Comment: "*... If this parameter is FALSE, the updated file includes existing resources unless they are explicitly deleted or replaced by using UpdateResource.*"

Comment: If RcData is text, you can rename your *.exe file to *.dll, drop in Visual Studio and edit it. That doesn't sound legal!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Now the problem is only a blank line the code adds (line 1), when I clear it, the exe works properly, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: @Ruan the "blank line" you are referring to is not a line at all. It is caused by the display of the WORD length that you are placing in front of the wstring character data. Why are you doing that? Where did you find that ">AUTOHOTKEY SCRIPT<" resources use length-prefixed strings? The original script doesn't appear to be using them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i don't understand, I was trying to follow an example and it was using the data in a vector, i don't think i need it, just replacing the data that is inside of the `wstring` would help, but I'm I'm not getting it.

Comment: @Ruan what example are you referring to? Was it specifically for AHK scripts, or for something else? Have you tried simply removing the `WORD`s altogether? `std::wstring data = L"MsgBox Test"; ... UpdateResource(..., &data[0], data.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau now it does not add the "blank line" anymore, but when I run the exe, looks like it does recognize just the `M` https://i.imgur.com/GvpEcBy.png, I was referring to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088057/updating-a-string-table-with-updateresource

Comment: @Ruan that example is creating an `RT_STRING` (string table) resource, which is not what you are creating. As for the encoding issue, AHK is clearly processing the 16bit Unicode characters as 8bit characters, so try using `std::string` instead of `std::wstring`: `std::string data = "MsgBox Test"; ... UpdateResource(..., &data[0], data.size());` And FYI, there is no need to cast to `void*` using `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: Thank you, I converted it to `std::string` now it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring`, as AHK is expecting 8bit characters, not 16bit characters. Also, you need to get rid of your `vector`, as AHK does not expect each line to be prefixed by its length.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void ReplaceStringTable() {

    HANDLE hRes = BeginUpdateResource( TEXT( "C:\\Users\\CAIO\\Documents\\Github\\main\\scripts\\ahkDebug\\Novo(a) AutoHotkey Script.exe" ), FALSE );
    if ( hRes != NULL ) {
        std::string data = "MsgBox Test";

        UpdateResource( hRes,
            RT_RCDATA,
            L">AUTOHOTKEY SCRIPT<", //MAKEINTRESOURCE( 1 ),
            1033, //MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT ),
            const_cast<char*>(data.c_str()),
            data.size() );

        EndUpdateResource( hRes, FALSE ); 
    }
}
```