# LoadString returns empty string

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to store positions of some objects in resource file and I've decided to store it in **STRINGTABLE** resource, because I couldn't find better type.
My resource file:

```
#include "resource.h"
// POSITIONS_ID = 10 defined in resource.h
STRINGTABLE
{
POSITIONS_ID "100 100 \
200 350 \
400 800"
}
```

I've tried to get this string differently, but the problem is the same
One of my attempts:

```
char* data = new char[100];
int length = LoadStringA(NULL, POSITIONS_ID, data, 100); // length = 0
cout << GetLastError() << endl // out 0, so there aren't any errors
                               // but data = "\0"
```

I've also tried to use `wchar_t` as type of data with `LoadStringW` function, but result is the same. I've tried `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` instead of `NULL` too.
I don't understand what is wrong.

Some more information:

```
HRSRC r = FindResource(Null, MAKEINTRESOURCE(POSITIONS_ID), RT_STRING) // return 0;
cout << GetLastError() << endl; // return 1814(The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file.)
```

So problem is that resource can't be found, but I still don't understand why.

Comment: It definitely has to be the module handle, not NULL. What number is `length`? Are you sure the resource compiler includes the header that defines POSITIONS_ID?

Comment: ```length``` is length of loaded string. I am sure, that header is included

Comment: What is the value of `length` that `LoadStringA` returns ?  _"...Zero if the string resource does not exist...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadstringa

Comment: It equals to 0, but GetLastError() is 0 too, so I think It has found the resource

Comment: Start with a baseline.  Look inside the executable to see if you can actually see that string.  If not, then you didn't build your application correctly.  Or better yet, load the executable as a resource in a resource editor (maybe Visual Studio if you have it) and see if that resource actually exists.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've opened exe in resource view and there is my STRINGTABLE, but when I open it there is **empty ID** and **value field is equal to 10 (the id I've used)** and **caption is equal to string with my cordinates**

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089163/1889329) to learn why querying for a non-existent string with ID 8 (when one with ID 10 exists) returns an empty string, alongside an error code of 0 (i.e. "success").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "resource.h" file I defined POSITIONS_ID this way `#define POSTIONS_ID 0010` to make defines look better, but for some reason leading zeros mustn't be used in resource ids.
Also I've find out, that when I use `FindResource` with type RT_STRING, I am looking for STRINGTABLE resource, that contains up to 16 string, so I have to use function this way `FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(POSITIONS_ID / 16 + 1), RT_STRING)`.
Thank everyone for help.

Comment: The leading zero makes it an octal number. `0010` is the value 8.

Comment: So, how much C does the [resource compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler) actually speak, and are there other cases where the C compiler/preprocessor and resource compiler silently disagree?

Comment: @IInspectable ["Old New Thing" - The Resource Compiler’s preprocessor is not the same as the C preprocessor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171004-00/?p=97126)

Comment: @ric I was more concerned about silent disagreement, although RC's expression evaluator—from the sounds of it—is well prepared to offer a multitude of such opportunities. I suppose the rules would be less surprising if we actually had them documented, however weird they might be.

Comment: Is it possible to purge some strings of an existing table (or move to the Neutral language), without breaking everything? Is there some "NOOP" placeholder to keep the 16 entities correct?